# web3Enable prompts sign-in to all of my installed extensions when I only want a single prompt for a single extension

Tags: polkadot-js-extension, browser-extension

web3Enable returns an array of all the injected sources/extensions. Is there any way to prevent it from prompting permissions for every installed extension and instead have it only throw out the one the user selects? I want the user to be able to choose from a list of extensions (like singular.app does it) without getting hit with unnecessary popups.

```
code Example:
const allInjected = await web3Enable('my cool dapp');
```

Answer (score 1):

This [talisman-connect](https://github.com/TalismanSociety/talisman-connect/blob/d5152e8a4d0f7236ef9775beb69f0981669d3508/packages/connect-wallets/README.md) package offers a solution to the problem that seems to be working well for us.

Comment: Nice. I get a bit flustered with all those popups triggering at once!